# ViewController reads data from firestore late

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I have username in firestore, whenever person logs in my app, I want to read that data(username) in firestore immediately, but it needs some time, if the problem is in slow internet, what other possible ways would you suggest to get my end result?

[image: gif for better understanding]

as yo can see in the gif above, loading username takes a little bit of time, but it is still a problem, I want it to be already loaded

```swift
   @IBOutlet weak var welcomeNameLabel: UILabel!
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
        readData()
        
    }
    
    func readData(){
        self.db.collection("users").getDocuments{ (snapshot, err) in
            
            if let err = err {
                print("error happened \(err)")
            }else {
                if let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
                if let currentUserDoc = snapshot?.documents.first(where: { ($0["uid"] as? String) == userId }) {
                    var welcomeName = currentUserDoc["username"] as! String
                    self.welcomeNameLabel.text = "Welcome, \(welcomeName)"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: did u try calling the ```readData``` method inside the ```viewDidLoad()```?

Comment: Is this the view controller the UI launches to on app start?

Comment: @udi `viewDidLoad` won't solve the problem and is also not where you want to get data incase if that data is cached and comes back synchronously.

Comment: @liquid no It's not, the app start is a Login page, after I login successfully, I make `rootViewController` my Tabbar which is located in a different storyboard from login

Comment: Why not load the document on app launch and store it somewhere to use throughout the app? Unless this is not the main user's name?

Comment: Firestore also does cache data on the client and so you can get a cached value when the view controller loads and then from the server after it loads and update the label if the value is different. Snapshot listeners also go straight from cache on first call so the value grab will be synchronous.